# How can I import only a couple of functions from a Ruby module?

Tags: ruby, import, function, module

Suppose I have a module with the methods : function1,function2,function3. I want to import function1 and function2 but not function3. Is there a way to do this in ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there is a clean way to just add the methods you want, but you can remove the methods that you don't want by using `undef_method`.

```
module Foo
  def function1
  end

  def function2
  end

  def function3
  end
end

module MiniFoo
  include Foo
  not_wanted_methods = Foo.instance_methods - %w(function1 function2)
  not_wanted_methods.each {|m| undef_method m}
end

class Whatever
  include MiniFoo
end
```

Comment: I had in mind something like this, but I thought maybe a cleaner way exists.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you control the source code to the module, I think the cleanest way would be to split the module in to more, uh, modular pieces.

If you only want some parts of a module, that's a pretty good sign that you could refactor that module into multiple modules that have less responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

Similar solution but a tad more automatic. I have no idea what kind of weird things that can happen though.

```
module Foo
  def m1
    puts "Hello from m1"
  end

  def m2
    puts "Hllo from m2"
  end
end

class Module
  alias :__include__ :include
  def include(mod, *methods)
    if methods.size > 0
        tmp  = mod.dup
        new_mod = Object.const_set("Mod#{tmp.object_id}", tmp)
        toremove = new_mod.instance_methods.reject { |m| methods.include? m.to_sym }
        toremove.each { |m| new_mod.send(:undef_method, m) }
        __include__(new_mod)
    else
      __include__(mod)
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

class Baz
  include Foo, :m2
end

bar = Bar.new
baz = Baz.new
p bar.methods - Object.methods
p baz.methods - Object.methods

=>

["m1", "m2"]
["m2"]
```