# How to import only methods wanted, no all library in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to use the `cd` method from fileutils:

```
require "fileutils"
```

Instead of doing:

```
FileUtils.cd(home/user/Documents)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
cd(home/user/Documents)
```

Can I do something like this in Ruby?

In Python, we can do:

```
from random import randint
print(randint(1,7))
```

instead of:

```
import random
print(random.randint(1,7))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import only a couple of functions from a Ruby module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700790/how-can-i-import-only-a-couple-of-functions-from-a-ruby-module)

Comment: Ruby is not Python, as I painfully get reminded each time I use Python :P . You can get `cd("home/user/Documents")` by `require "fileutils"; include FileUtils`, but I do not suggest you use it (what it does is makes the current object inherit from `FileUtils` module).

Comment: @Amadan also it makes _all other_ method of FileUtils available in the same manner.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Indeed so. That part was in response to "I want to do something like this: `cd(home/user/Documents)`", and I could have been clearer (though the implication is quite strong, as the code snippet I gave does not reference `cd` in any manner)

Comment: @RigbyK : How are you thinking to handle methods which depend on each other? You might think that you need only method `foo`, but when executing `foo`, it might also require method `bar` without you being aware of.

Comment: @user1934428: In Python the entire module is executed, but only the noted entities are imported for use. Inside the module's code everything is still available. Python's import statements don't mean that only the noted functions are loaded; it just affects which objects are available to the current namespace. It is in a way similar to using `private` in Ruby to mark methods that are available inside the class but not from the outside, though the purpose and domain are different (Ruby does it to protect object integrity, Python does it to protect the importing environment from pollution).